# Knockout Js - Using with inside if condition

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

The `isAdmin` property inside `foreach` is related in authorization class.

I am getting an error saying `isAdmin` is not defined. Is it because I am using `isAdmin` in `foreach`? How can I use a use property in `with` in `foreach`.

```
<div data-bind="with: authorization">
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <!-- ko if: isAdmin -->
    <td><a href="#" class="icon-trash" rel="tooltip" title="Delete" ></a></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, it is not working because the `foreach` binding gets its own context.  Use `$parent` to access the parent authorization context.

```
<!-- ko if: $parent.isAdmin -->
<td><a href="#" class="icon-trash" rel="tooltip" title="Delete" ></a></td>
<!-- /ko -->
```